# Created a doubly linked list but it does not print anything after giving a print function?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I just created a doubly linked list for the first time and it does not give any output despite giving a print function. There's definitely some small mistake that I am not able to figure out AND There's a small question too that i wanna ask that how should I debug these codes to find out the mistakes myself. Please comment any lecture of any tutorial to debug code in VScode
Thank you in advance
**Here is the code :**

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
    struct node* prev;
};
struct node* head;

struct node* getnewnode(int x){
    struct node* tempnode = new node();
    tempnode->data=x;
    tempnode->next=NULL;
    tempnode->prev=NULL;
    return tempnode;    
};
void insertathead(int x){
    struct node* newnode = getnewnode(x);
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head == newnode;
        return;
    }
    head->prev=newnode;
    newnode->next=head;
    head=newnode;
}
void print(){
    struct node* tempprint = head;
    while (tempprint != NULL)
    {
        cout<<tempprint->data<<"_";
        tempprint=tempprint->next;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

void reverseprint(){
    struct node* tempreverse = head;
    if (tempreverse == NULL)
    {
        return;//empty list
    }
    while (tempreverse->next != NULL)
    {
        tempreverse = tempreverse->next;
    }
    //now traversing backwards using prev
    while (tempreverse != NULL)
    {
        cout<<tempreverse->data<<"_";
        tempreverse=tempreverse->prev;
    }
    
}
void insertattail(int x){
    struct node* newnode = getnewnode(x);
    struct node* temptail = head;
    while (temptail->next != NULL)
    {
        temptail = temptail->next;
    }
    temptail->next= newnode;
    newnode->prev=temptail;
    newnode->next=NULL;
}
int main(){
    head=NULL;//empty list
    insertathead(2);
    insertathead(4);
    insertathead(8);
    insertattail(3);
    //list - 2_4_8_3
    print();
    reverseprint();
    print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OT: `struct node* newnode = ...` in c++ you can omit the `struct` before `node*` in all places except `struct node{`

Comment: Using onlinegdb to debug your code it crashed on line 59: `while (temptail->next != NULL)` here: [https://onlinegdb.com/wm83SNGBx](https://onlinegdb.com/wm83SNGBx)

Comment: Your bug is `head == newnode;` that is a comparison not an assignment. Also in `insertattail()` you never check if head is null. Because of the first bug head was null.

Comment: @drescherjm Thank you for that super fast answer sir . Got the problem and now it runs perfectly.

Comment: You probably want to delete the question. This question most likely will be closed as a typo or duplicate. That is why I did not answer.

Comment: I ended up seeing the problem by stepping through the code line by line in the debugger and setting breakpoints to narrow down where the problem was. Also when it crashed gdb showed me that `temptail` was null

Comment: Great observation and skills sir . Kudos. @drescherjm

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in such a short period of time.
There was a bug that was causing all the trouble that is on the line 21
I was comparing head and newnode instead i should have assingned the value of the newnode to head .
Thank you